# Color markers on Google map using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hello I'm new to rails in general.

I'm building a web application using rails in which I need to render different people locations using google map.

Basically I want to generate different color markers depending on user group. Now how do I do that processing in the javascript file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MapIconMaker](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapiconmaker/1.0/docs/examples.html) Library for coloring markers, you can define many colors to manege your groups:

```
var GROUP_1 = MapIconMaker.createMarkerIcon({primaryColor: "#04b404"});
var GROUP_2 = MapIconMaker.createMarkerIcon({primaryColor: "#58acf4"});
var GROUP_3 = MapIconMaker.createMarkerIcon({primaryColor: "#ff8000"});

point = new GLatLng(latitude, longitude);
marker = new GMarker(point,{icon: GROUP_1});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, other than the default icon, you must use an image for the icon in other coloring scenarios as described here : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions

In an implementation I've used before, it looked similar to this:

```
                $.each(data, function() {
                  var post_position = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: post_position,
                    map: map,
                    title: this.title,
                    icon: "images/purple_icon.png"
                });
                markerArray.push(marker);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) and [customize](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers) your markers according to whatever rule you want.

See [screencasts](http://www.youtube.com/user/TheApneadiving) (I know res is poor but vote on Railscasts!).